# Calculate Known Angle's Measurement

Tags: javascript, function, math, trigonometry

I'm coding one function and it's must calculate a measurement. I know 2 angles measurement and need to calculate the given angle's measurement. What kind of way I should use?
I'm adding my js function here:

```js
if (RAngle != 0) var x = ((a90mea - a135mea) / 45) * (180 - newAngle);
return x;
```

An example: a90mea = 24(it means 90degree's measurement 24mm), a135mea = 20, and new angle is 172. How should I change my function? Or can it give the right numbers?

Comment: I don't understand what your issue is; are you getting wrong values for `x`?

Comment: What is angle measurement in millimeters?

Comment: if i give 90 degree i get 24mm. And issue is if i use 172 angle i get wrong x.

Comment: `if i give 90 degree i get 24mm` - I don't understand this phrase

Comment: Okay, we are calculating glass's width. If there is 90 degree between two glasses we are decreasing 24 mm from each glasses. And we can only know two degrees decrease measurements. And if our customer wants 172 degree's mm I need to calculate this mm. This is why i need function for it. Is it enough for understanding?